# Loop jquery animation

Tags: jquery, animation, loops

I'm going nuts trying to figure this out.

I have two divs with a background image of rain that I've animated with jquery to go from top:-100% to top:100%.
I want the divs to loop so the visual effect is that a continuous stream of rain comes down.

I can get the animation to loop, but it waits until the full cycle is complete until it starts again, so there is a second or two where you see the animation ending.

My solution was to have two identical divs. The first div would begin animation, then when it reaches top:0%, I want the second div to begin. The first div then needs to loop when the second div has also reached top:0% and so on.

I can create a variable that gives the value of the div position, but firstly it's in pixels (I need percent) and secondly it only gives me the figure once on doc ready (I need it to continually update)

Is this achievable? Here's my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //RAIN
        function rain1() {
            $("#rain1").animate({ top: '100%'}, 4000, 'linear', function() {
                $(this).css("top", "-100%").delay(4000);
                rain1();
    });
        }

        function rain2() {
            $("#rain2").delay(4000).animate({ top: '100%'}, 4000, 'linear', function() {
                $(this).css("top", "-100%");
                rain2();
    });
        }

        $('a.control-rain').click(function(){
            rain1();
            rain2();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did nothing more than resetting the top to 0% in your code iso -100%. I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Working Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/ZHSKj/1/

Comment: no sorry that's not what I was asking. My issue is the same in your fiddle. Sorry I should have explained that my divs with the rain graphics in have 100% height. This is why they both start with -100% height, so they appear off screen. When the first div reaches 0% height, it will fill the screen and the second div then needs to be triggered to avoid the 100% gap you would get if you just looped the first div on it's own.

Comment: Can you please add your html to the question as well? I would love to debug it, even though i am not a pro at css.